# Preserve new version of GeForce Experience when downgrading NV driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-geforce, downgrade, geforce-experience

I have a GeForce GTX 800M series GPU on my laptop. For whatever reason, I prefer a specific (somewhat old) version of driver, but I also like trying new drivers occasionally.

The problem is, when downgrading driver to my favorite version, I can't seem to keep GeForce Experience: it'll either be downgraded to the bundled version in the driver, or removed altogether. Strangely, if the driver installer detects a newer version of PhysX already installed, it won't touch it, retaining the newer version of PhysX. So, is there any way to retain GFE?

If that matters, my driver preference is NVIDIA 353.62 WHQL (Win10).

Comment: There is a good possibility the version of GeForce experience is dependent upon driver version. But you can certainly do a custom install and choose what to install/remove. Have you done this?

Comment: @Appleoddity Certainly! There's a checkbox for GFE when doing a custom install. If it's checked then GFE is replaced with the bundled version. If it's blank then GFE is removed. No luck :(